# Looking to find my voice classification

Tags: voice

I'm an 18 yr. old male, looking to maybe get into singing. On a bad day my lowest is C2 and on a good one A1, if vocal fry/subharmonics are not considered. My highest sits somewhere between A3 and C4, without the use of falsetto. Falsetto can bring me up to A5 but it sounds bad lol. What would you classify me as?

Comment: Why do you consider it important to have your voice classified? Genuine question.

Comment: If you wish to join a choir they often expect you to know?

Comment: Posting a clip of you singing, even a scale up and down your range, would probably be more useful

Comment: @Mr.Boy - we get quite a few questions such as this on the site. True, you may need to proffer that information before joining a choir, but I'd have thought that at the audition, the choirmaster would be knowledgable enough to make that decision - and there are always those singers who have a larger range than just 'baritone' or whatever. At 18, and 'looking to *maybe* getting into singing', I'd be interested in an answer to my comment.I've been singing for 60+ yrs, and still don't know my category, so it obviously doesn't matter to me!!

Comment: @Tim I guess people just are interested. They like labels :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are a bass.  You are young so your tessitura may change slightly with time.